# Conjunction lest, speaking of reasons ? where it is more preferable to use "lest"?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, negation

Can we always use "lest" to provide explanations reasoning an action, status, etc. ?

Compare:

1. > She was worried lest the refuges be suffering cold weather.
2. > She was worried about the refuges to be lived in cold weather without a suitable shelter.

The question is where we must use this conjunction ? 
Can it be used in ordinary/academic written English ? (I do not see this conjunction very often)

Comment: Use it about as often as you use "in lieu" or the exclamation "alas".  The problem I think that those who are going to read your writing or listen to your speech may not be equipped to understand "lest"...

Comment: What do you mean ? Is it archaic or very literary English? I've check Oxford; it says it is both formal and literary !

Comment: It's not as archaic as "shoppe" or "boga", but it's not everyday speech either.  How many times a day do you hear "to and fro" or "lo and behold"?  Same with "lest".  It's just ***not common***.  Consider that among your *interlocutors* there can be people who have never read Shakespeare...

Comment: Many thanks, so it is more common in English literature, e.g, Shakespear

Comment: ... or in presidential speeches, or in Sunday sermons...

Comment: 1. The word you're looking for is *refugees*, not *refuges*. 2. "...to be lived in cold weather..." is not grammatical, and I'm having trouble figuring out what you meant to say instead. Perhaps "...living in cold weather..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions succinctly:

1. Where must we use the conjunction?
   ***There is no requirement for its use. Other words can always be used in lieu of it.***
2. Can it be used in ordinary written English?
   ***Yes, though it is uncommon.***
3. Can it be used in academic written English?
   ***Yes.***

The word *lest* is one of those words that doesn't come up much in conversation, as several commenters have already stated. The one time I hear it come up conversationally is in the ***so as to prevent any possibility that*** conjunction. Here are some examples from recent memory:

- He replaced the hose with the hole in it *lest* he drown the next time he used his SCUBA gear.
- I would refill your brake fluid *lest* they fail and send you off the side of the road on a sharp turn.
- We left the city *lest* we be thrown in chains for a crime we didn't commit.